# If/Then AMPScript Content for Points Balance

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I want to display different content based on a user's point balance in our app. Not sure if I'm doing this correctly. Basically, if they have less than 1,000 points I want to tell them to "report prices" and otherwise, I want to tell them to enter the Gas Card Giveaway.

This is what I have right now:

```
Hi %%first_name%%! You have %%=FormatNumber(point_balance, "N0", "en-US")=%% points.
[ if %%point_balance%% >=1,000 then ]%%
<a href="%%= RedirectTo(Concat('http://routing.gasbuddy.com/home)) =%%">Report prices</a>%% in GasBuddy today to earn more points!
[ else ]%%
<a href="%%= RedirectTo(Concat('http://routing.gasbuddy.com/home)) =%%">Redeem your points</a>%% and enter the gas card giveaway today.
```

Does this look correct?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear how you intend to display the string `http://routing.gasbuddy.com/home))`. If for some reason you want to display it as it appears in your code, then you can simplify your AMPscript using the `iif()` function, so your AMPscript would look like:

```
Hi %%first_name%%! You have %%=FormatNumber(point_balance, "N0", "en-US")=%% points. http://routing.gasbuddy.com/home)) 

%%=iif(point_balance >=1000,'Report prices in GasBuddy today to earn more points!','Redeem your points and enter the gas card giveaway today.')=%%
```

If the value of `point_balance` in your sendable Data Extension is `123.56` then this AMPscript would be rendered as:

> Hi Frank! You have 124 points. http://routing.gasbuddy.com/home))
>
> Redeem your points and enter the gas card giveaway today.

If the value of `point_balance` is `1231.56`, then this would be rendered as:

> Hi Frank! You have 1,232 points. http://routing.gasbuddy.com/home))
>
> Report prices in GasBuddy today to earn more points!

This doesn't look quite right, but again I'm unsure how you require the string `http://routing.gasbuddy.com/home))` to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have some syntax issues in your AMPScript and your conditional didn't match what you described.

No need to use the `redirectto()` and `concat()` on your static URLs.  Link wrapping on will work without it.

I'd write it like this:

```
%%[

var @first_name, @point_balance
set @first_name = AttributeValue("first_name")
set @point_balance = AttributeValue("point_balance")

]%%

Hi %%=v(@first_name)=%%!  You have <b>%%=format_number(@point_balance, "N0", "en-US")=%%</b> points.

%%[ if @point_balance < 1000 OR empty(@point_balance) then ]%%

<a href="http://routing.gasbuddy.com/home">Report prices</a> in GasBuddy today to earn more points!

%%[ else ]%%

<a href="http://routing.gasbuddy.com/home">Redeem your points</a> and enter the gas card giveaway today.

%%[ endif ]%%
```